# Python - inspect.isfunction and functools.partial

Tags: python

Why call `inspect.isfunction` to a `functools.partial` wrapping a function returns `False`?

I've been doing a lot of research, I've found numerous issues like [this](https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/79071) where some comment that what I'm trying should return `True`.

Even with more complex objects such as asynchronous functions, it does well. Why not do it with functions?

```py
import functools
import inspect


def sin(a, b):
    print(a * b)


async def asin(a, b):
    print(a * b)


sin_partial = functools.partial(sin, 5)
asin_partial = functools.partial(asin, 5)

print(inspect.isfunction(sin))
print(inspect.isfunction(sin_partial))
print('----------')
print(inspect.iscoroutinefunction(asin))
print(inspect.iscoroutinefunction(asin_partial))
```

**Output:**

```
True
False
----------
True
True
```

I expected `inspect.isfunction(sin_partial)` to return `True`.

Comment: What's the issue here? do you expect ``print(inspect.isfunction(sin_partial))`` to return ``true``?

Comment: `inspect.iscoroutinefunction` returning `True` for `partial` objects that wrap coroutine functions is a weird special case that probably never should have been added. `inspect.isfunction` has no such weird special case.

Comment: @user2357112 Does that mean it's okay for `inspect.function(sin_partial)` to return `False`? In the comments of the issue that I linked there are some comments that seem to indicate that it returns `True`.

Comment: @FlanaBan: The person who said that `inspect.isfunction` would unwrap partials was wrong. `inspect.isfunction` does not unwrap partials, and I don't think it ever did. That person's wrong claim was what motivated changing `inspect.iscoroutinefunction` to unwrap partials, which is one of the reasons I consider the `inspect.iscoroutinefunction` partial unwrapping behavior to be a mistake.

Answer (score 2):

Python's `async` functions are [`coroutine` objects](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-coroutine), not functions.

Python's `functools.partial`s are [partial objects](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#partial-objects), not functions.

`inspect.iscoroutinefunction` is just a special case to handle coroutines.
`inspect` simply does not have a special function handler for `partial`s.

If you wish to detect both `partial` and `coroutine` as functions, you could just check if they are `callable`.

```
print(callable(sin_partial))
print(callable(asin_partial))
```

Output

```
True
True
```

If this does not fit for you, you could create your own partial checker wrapper that handles it:

```
from typing import Callable 

import inspect
import functools

def isfunction(f: Callable) -> bool:
    return isinstance(f, functools.partial) or inspect.iscoroutinefunction(f) or inspect.isfunction(f)
```

Comment: I don't use callable for compelling reasons. Many other things can be callable.

You say that async functions are not functions, that's correct but in the example I use `inspect.iscoroutinefunction` and it works fine. I just hoped it would work just as well for functions too.

Comment: `async` functions are functions. They *return* coroutine objects. You can call `inspect.isfunction(asin)` and see that it returns `True`, or if you don't trust that, you can check `isinstance(asin, types.FunctionType)`.