# inspect.isfunction() in Python, is not working as intended

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-urls

I was building a simple project in Django. Now inside an app, we have got the *urls.py*
So out of curiosity, when I tried to find whether *'path'* that I imported is a class or function, but everytime I got that its not a function.
Everywhere (Stackoverflow post, or any other site) I am finding that the *'path'* is a function. Can somebody explain this?

Moreover, it is also printing 'False' for

```
inspect.isclass(path)
```

This is the content of *'urls.py'*

```
import inspect
from django.urls import path
print(inspect.isfunction(path))
```

It printed 'False', whereas it should have printed 'True', what happening actually?

Comment: `path` is defined in `conf.py` as `partial(_path, Pattern=RoutePattern)`. (source code: https://github.com/django/django/blob/12ffcfc350a19bbfbc203126a9b6c84b5e0d0ba2/django/urls/conf.py#L94C8-L94C44). For objects like this (the result of calling `functools.partial`), `inspect.isfunction` returns False. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76207316/python-inspect-isfunction-and-functools-partial

Comment: There are many things in Python that are *callable* without being instances of `types.FunctionType`, which is the only thing `inspect.isfunction` checks.

Comment: @slothrop Thank you, I get it now. Yes it answers my question :)